# UITableView original content new content overlapping after reloadData

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata, overlapping

I encountered a problem with the UITableView. I have a table that list out an array of items. A segmented control that controls how the table's content should be sorted, by rating/date. What bothers me is that some of the table cells' text is not clearly displayed, those cell display two array items in it instead of one, hence the two items overlap on and make the content unreadable. However, if I click on the cell, the overlapping will gone, the right item will be displayed. I am wondering is this the problem of Xcode? the graphic card memory sometimes is not refreshed timely or what?

One thing worth noticing is that in my customized cell, there are 5 labels, Four with short content (title, date, etc) and a longer one (4 lines of text, summary of cell content). Only the long label's content could get overlapping corruption, the other 4 labels are always fine. And the overlapping corruption only happens to certain cells. Does anyone who have the same problem before?

Comment: Please post your code - I'm interested to see what you did in "heightForRowAtIndexPath" and explain how you defined the table view in the storyboard/xib

Comment: Ha, thanks so much, I some inspiration from your comment, the problem is that I forgot to check the "clears graphics context" property of the long label. No wonder that the rest labels are fine but only this one has problem. Once I check it, problem solved.